# How to raise an error / return a {"foo":["This field is required."]} response in Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have a view and I need to check that a field is given before calling serializer.save to ensure I don't get a dictionary key error:

```
class BarView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BarSerializer
    queryset = Bar.objects.all()
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        if 'foo' not in self.request.data:
            raise ParseError('foo field required.')
        foo = get_object_or_404(Foo, pk=self.request.data['foo'])
        if foo.counter == 10:
            raise ParseError('foo limit reached.')
        return serializer.save(user=self.request.user, foo=foo)
```

Instead of returning `"foo field required."` I would like to return a message the same as Django REST returns e.g. `{"foo":["This field is required."]}`

Is there a better way to do this?  Perhaps validating the foo field alone with the serializer?

**Update**: I forgot to mention the user field is also required.

The model for Bar is:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, editable=False)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, db_index=True)
```

Comment: Does Your `serializer` returns on `is_valid()` value `True` ?

Comment: Is `foo` field a part of your model?

Comment: Yes, I just added the model to the original question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes,

Simply look at docs: [Validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

(*I assumed that field `foo` is part of `Bar` model, if not please add it to `fields` in `Meta`*):

Add validation to BarSerializer:

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_foo(self, value):
        if not value:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("foo field required.")
        if Foo.objects.filter(pk=value, counter__gte=10).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("foo limit reached.")
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
```

And then create Your View by extending this:

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):        
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
             return super(BarView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except ValidationError as e:
             return Response(e.detail, , status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def create(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        try:
            self.perform_create(serializer)       
        except DjangoValidationError as e:
            raise ValidationError(e.messages)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

    def perform_create(serializer):
        # do your stuff
        serializer.save()
```

Comment: How would I save the request user in post (this is also a required field)?

Comment: @tyebillion improved answer to fit your needs, simply use this class insead of `CreateAPIView`

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, the best way to do this is to make the `foo` field required in your serializer using [`extra_kwargs`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments) option in the `Meta` class.**

DRF will automatically handle the validation for you. You don't need to raise this validation error yourself.

```
class Meta:
    ...
    extra_kwargs = {'foo': {'required':True}} # make 'foo' a required field.
```

Now, whenever the `foo` field is not passed in the `request`, there will be a key `foo` in the `serializer.errors` dictionary and its value will be `This field is required.`

Also, create a `validate_foo()` function which will validate for the limit  of `foo_object.counter`.

```
def validate_foo(self, value):
    self.foo_object = get_object_or_404(Foo, pk=value) # get the 'foo' object
    if self.foo_object.counter == 10: # check for limits
        raise serializers.ValidationError('foo limit reached.') # raise error
    return value # must return the value at the end
```

**FINAL CODE:**

**serializers.py**

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        ...
        extra_kwargs = {'foo': {'required':True}} # make 'foo' a required field.

    def validate_foo(self, value):
        self.foo_object = get_object_or_404(Foo, pk=value)
        if self.foo_object.counter == 10: 
            raise serializers.ValidationError('foo limit reached.') 
        return value
```

**views.py**

In your views, you need to override `perform_create()` and pass `user` and  `serializer.foo_object` to `serializer.save()` function.

```
class BarView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BarSerializer
    queryset = Bar.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(user=self.request.user, foo=serializer.foo_object)
```

Comment: I get an error: Exception Type: AttributeError, Exception Value: 
'BarSerializer' object has no attribute 'foo_object', on the last line "return serializer..."

Comment: Have you added `validate_foo()` function to your serializer? In that function, we are setting `foo_object` as an attribute on the serializer and then using this value when calling `serializer.save()`.

Comment: Yes.  I also have read_only_fields = ('foo',) in the Meta section of my serializer.

Comment: You are getting this error because of declaring `foo` as a read-only field. When a field is read-only, it won't be considered for validation and hence `validate_foo` is never called thereby never setting the `foo_object` on the serializer. Try removing `foo` as read-only field and it should work perfectly.

Comment: I still get the same error: 'BarSerializer' object has no attribute 'foo_object'.  Shouldn't the validation go in the model?

Comment: Please post the code for `BarSerializer` which you are using. I think it would be better to handle the validation at serializer and it should reach the model after passing all serializer validations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88937/discussion-between-tyebillion-and-rahul-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

You can return `Response` with user defined message

```
if 'foo' not in self.request.data:
    return Response({"foo":["This field is required."]})
```

Comment: Unfortunately returning Response in perform_create does not work.  Instead of raising an exception I get Exception Type: KeyError, Exception Value: 'foo'.